# What does mean number near extended attributes in ls -l@ output?

Tags: ls, xattr

What does mean number near extended attributes in ls -l@ output and how i can get it?

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 41 root  wheel         1394 Nov  7 14:50 bin
com.apple.FinderInfo      32 //this number
com.apple.rootless     0 //and this
```

Comment: What is `@`????

Comment: Note that in MacOS, `@` is a valid flag for the `ls` command to display a directory or file's extended attributes.

Comment: Not related to C language. Please don't use unrelated tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is MacOS specific I think. Maybe you want to take a look at the `xattr` command [here](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html). The number displayed by `ls` is the size in bytes of the attribute. The meaning of the value of a particular attribute is arbitrary (as is the set of extended attributes a file may have) and really depends on the attribute itself.

To be consistent with your question tags, you can also access extended attributes [programatically](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/listxattr.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/listxattr) from C by including `sys/xattr.h`.

Answer (score 1):

This number means sizeof extended attribute in bytes.
You can get it by `getxattr` from `sys/xattr.h`